# Parsing and storing a json response in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

My JSON response has the following structure.
How should i parse it to store in a list in java with the structure maintained.
Does GSON provide a solution or should i use multidimensional array list?

I need to pass each of the tag array to a different view pager what approach should I follow.

```
{
  "tag": [
    {
      "listing_count": 5,
      "listings": [
        {
          "source": "source1",
          "data": {
            "image": "image1",
            "name": "name1"
          },
          "name": "name1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "listing_count": 5,
      "listings": [
        {
          "source": "source2",
          "data": {
            "image": "imag2",
            "name": "name2"
          },
          "name": "name2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have created the classes as suggested in the answer..I am having trouble creating the GSON response class.
This is what I have created:

```
public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz,
            Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener, Gson gson) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.mClazz = clazz;
        this.mListener = listener;
        mGson = gson;
    }
```

Comment: While using the Gson u can store the data until the app kill when application kill the data loss.One option have to store the data in shared preference as a json string . when u needed the data,u parse the data  and display. Other wise u have to use the database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick info..
how can I create a class for GSON to act on for the above structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gson class should be something like this:

```
public class TagList {

ArrayList<Tag> tags;

public static class Tag {
    int listing_count;
    ArrayList<Listings> listings;

    public int getListing_count() {
        return listing_count;
    }

    public void setListing_count(int listing_count) {
        this.listing_count = listing_count;
    }

    public ArrayList<Listings> getListings() {
        return listings;
    }

    public void setListings(ArrayList<Listings> listings) {
        this.listings = listings;
    }

}

public static class Listings {
    String source;
    Data data;
    String name;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public static class Data {
    String image;
    String name;

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I'v been stuck at creating the GSON response class.
Do i need to create a different GSON response for each list (tag and listings) ?